# Enhance Exporting Report to csv/excel using yii

Tags: yii, phpmyadmin

My system is working fine for small database and my report is generates from at least 5 table of phpmyadmin after certain limit of data load '500 internal server error' will come.I want enhance exporting a report to csv/excel from phpmyadmin using yii for larger database.

Comment: A 500 error is a web server error that points to a configuration type error. You need to look at the web server logs to get a clue to the details of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this extension to export to CSV. http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/csvexport/ 
I have created an action that I can attach to any controller that I need to export.

```
<?php

class Csv extends CAction {

    public $field_list;

    public function run() {
        $controller = $this->getController();

         /* Disable the logging because it should not run on this function */
        foreach (\Yii::app()->log->routes as $route)        {
            if ($route instanceof \CWebLogRoute) {
                $route->enabled = false;
            }
        }
        \Yii::import('core.extensions.ECSVExport.ECSVExport');
        //use the existing filters
        $model_name = $controller->modelName();
        $model = new $model_name('search');
        $dataProvider = $model->search();

        $criteria = $dataProvider->criteria;

        //remove the pagination
        $dataProvider->setPagination(false);

        //changing the criteria to only select what we want
        $criteria->select = implode(',', $this->field_list);
        $dataProvider->setCriteria($criteria);

        //export to CSV
        $csv = new \ECSVExport($dataProvider);
        if(isset($_GET['test'])) {
            echo $csv->toCSV();
        } else {
            \Yii::app()->getRequest()->sendFile($controller->modelName() . '_'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv', $csv->toCSV(), "text/csv", false);
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

field_list are the fields that I need to export.

For the controller I add

```
/**
 * @return array actions to be mapped to this controller
 */
public function actions(){
   return array(
    'csv'=>array(
          'class'=>'core.components.actions.Csv',
          'field_list'=>array('t.id', 't.name', 't.status'),
        ),
    );
}
/**
```

I use the same search as in the controller because it suits me and because I use http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/remember-filters-gridview/ I actually can export exactly what is on the screen. Change the field list to what you need. Remember to give access to the csvAction function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use yiiexcell extension for that: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiiexcel/ it is simple wrapper for PHPExcel http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/107442